# Karma + requirejs: Karma not able to run my angular modules and controllers

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, karma-jasmine

**Karma + AngularJS + requirejs: Karma not able to run my angular modules and controllers**. 
When I am trying to execute my tests it gives me this error:
" Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'DemoController' is not a function, got undefined"

I am pretty new to angular and karma/requirejs test frameworks. Found couple of posts online to set up karma+require for my angular project. So I followed the steps mentioned here 
http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/RequireJS.html
http://monicalent.com/blog/2015/02/11/karma-tests-angular-js-require-j/

I also referred couple of posts on stack overflow that said may be I am missing the module in which the controller is defined. but even after doing so I am getting the same error.
I think there is something that I am missing in terms of either configuration or the paths to my js files in karma.conf and/or test-main.js.

Here is how my project structure looks like

- AngularForKarma

  - lib

    - angular.js
    - angular.min.js
    - require.js
    - angular-mocks.js
- node_modules
- src

  - main.js
  - app.js
  - Controller

    - DemoController.js
- test

  - karma.conf
  - test-main.js
  - Controller

    - test.js
- package.json

Here is how each file looks

- **main.js - main file for my require.js**

  ```
  requirejs.config({
  baseUrl : "/src",
  paths : {
   angular : '../lib/angular.min',
   // Main Controller
   main_ctrl : '/src/DemoController',
  },

  shim : {
   angular : {
      exports : "angular"
   },
  }
  });

  require([ 'angular', 'main_ctrl' ], function() {
  'use strict';
   console.log('Inside main.js');
   angular.bootstrap(document, [ 'angularForKarma' ]);
  });
  ```
- **app.js**

  ```
  define([ 'angular' ], function(angular) {
    var app = angular.module('AngularForKarma', []);
    return app;
  });
  ```
- **DemoController.js**

  ```
  define([ 'angular', 'app'], function(angular, angularForKarma) {
  angularForKarma.controller("DemoController", function($scope) {
      $scope.compareValues = function(value1, value2) {
          console.log('compareValues.................');
          $scope.text = 'Hello World!';
          if (angular.equals(value1, value2)) {
              return true;
          }

          return false;
      };
      $scope.compareValues();
  });
  });
  ```

  - **karma.conf**

  module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

  ```
  // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
  basePath: '../..',


  // frameworks to use
  // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
  frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],


  // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
  files: [
    'AngularForKarma/test/test-main.js',
    {pattern: 'AngularForKarma/lib/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'AngularForKarma/src/**/*.js', included: false},
    {pattern: 'AngularForKarma/test/**/*.js', included: false}
  ],


  // list of files to exclude
  exclude: [
      'AngularForKarma/src/main.js'
  ],


  // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
  // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
  preprocessors: {
  },


  // test results reporter to use
  // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
  // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
  reporters: ['progress'],


  // web server port
  port: 9876,


  // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
  colors: true,


  // level of logging
  // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
  logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,


  // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
  autoWatch: true,


  // start these browsers
  // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
  browsers: ['Chrome'],


  // Continuous Integration mode
  // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
  singleRun: false,

  // Concurrency level
  // how many browser should be started simultanous
  concurrency: Infinity
  })}
  ```

  - **test-main.js**

  /

  ```
  //Get a list of all the test files to include
  var allTestFiles = [];
  var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;
  Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function(file) {
    if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
      // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
      // If you require sub-dependencies of test files to be loaded as-is (requiring file extension)
      // then do not normalize the paths
      // var normalizedTestModule = file.replace(/^\/base\/|\.js$/g, '');
      // allTestFiles.push(normalizedTestModule);
      }
  });

  for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
    if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
      allTestFiles.push(file);
    }
  }

  require.config({
  // Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your config file
  baseUrl: '/base/AngularForKarma/src',
  // dynamically load all test files
  deps: allTestFiles,

  // we have to kickoff jasmine, as it is asynchronous
  callback: window.__karma__.start,

  paths: {
   angular: '../lib/angular',
   angularMocks: '../lib/angular-mocks',
   // Main Controller
   main_ctrl : '../src/Controller/DemoController'
  },
  shim: {
   angular: { exports: 'angular' },
   angularMocks: { deps: ['angular'] }
  }
  });
  ```

Here is how my test file looks

- **test.js**

  ```
  use strict';
  define(['angular', 'app', 'angularMocks'], function (angular, app) {
  describe('demoCtrl', function() {
  var scope; // we'll use these in our tests

  // mock Application to allow us to inject our own dependencies
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('AngularForKarma'));

  // mock the controller for the same reason and include $rootScope and $controller
  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
      console.log("inside beforeEach");
      // create an empty scope
      scope = $rootScope.$new();

      // declare the controller and inject our empty scope
      $controller('DemoController', {
          $scope : scope
      });
  }));

  // tests start here
  it('should have variable text = "Hello World!"', function() {
      console.log("inside first test");
      expect(scope.text).toBe('Hello World!');
  });
  it('should compare values"', function() {
      console.log("inside 2nd test");
      expect(scope.compareValues('Anup', 'Anup')).toBe(true);
  });
  // it('should compare values"', function() {
  //  expect(scope.compareValues('Anup', 'Shreyas')).toBe(true);
  // });
  });
  });
  ```

Can anyone tell me where am I making a mistake? I am stuck on this for last 3-4 days now but still not able to figure out why is it not loading my controllers and modules

Thanks